# Hook javascript to dropdownlist change

Tags: c#, javascript, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

¡Hola!

My current task is to have a page where, with a dropdownlist, a user can select a deck title. Once a title is selected, the page should postback with details on that deck.

Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
@model IEnumerable<SCATChartsMVC.Models.Charts_DeckList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

    if (IsPost) { ViewBag.Title = "We posted back!"; }
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@{ var list = ViewData.Model.Select(cl => new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Value = cl.RecNum.ToString(),
                                    Text = cl.DeckTitle.ToString()
                                });
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Charts_DeckList", FormMethod.Post)) 
{ 
    @Html.DropDownList("deckTitles", list, "---------select---------")

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Charts_DeckList", new { id = list.ElementAt(4).Text }, "")

}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $("deckTitles").change(function () {
        if ($("#deckTitles").val() != "") {
            var test = {};
            test.url = "/Charts_DeckList/Details";
            test.type = "POST";
            test.data = JSON.stringify($('#deckTitles').val());
            test.datatype = "json";
            test.contentType = "application/json";
            test.success = true;
            test.error = function () { alert("Error!"); };
            $.ajax(test);
        }
    })
</script>
```

The input tag and ActionLink under Html.BeginForm were for my own testing purposes; the ActionLink works correctly if I specify the element. I'm hoping to be able to pass something similar back whenever a user clicks a selection, as opposed to whenever they hit the "details" button.

The submit input tag does not work. It does route properly to Charts_DeckList/Details, but the parameter in the action is always null.

I'm just getting into the whole MVC/Web rigamarole, so there's a lot I don't know that I'm not even aware I don't know. While I've seen a number of different resources on the internet suggesting different things, much of the web development jargon is lost on me at this point in time, and much of the way these things work under the hood is lost on me since VS seems to put together so much of it automagically.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

barrick's suggestion below is correct!

I also had to move the script tags up into the BeginForm brackets, heads up.

Comment: You problem is not moving the script tags. Its recommended they be at the bottom. As for the script, this line `$("deckTitles").change(function ()` should be `$("#deckTitles").change(function ()` As for the submit not working, you need to post you action method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the ID of the `DropDownList` there, the first argument sets the `name` attribute of the dropdown (used to identify the value in the POST variable collection on server postback) - you'll need to add another argument to set the ID:

```
@Html.DropDownList("deckTitles", list, "---------select---------", new { @id = "deckTitles" });
```

You can then pick up the selected value in the jQuery as follows:

```
$("#deckTitles option:selected").val();
```

Comment: This is wrong. Html helpers will render the `id` attribute based on its first parameter. It is not necessary to use `new { @id = "deckTitles" }`. You can also use `$('#deckTitles').val();` to get the value